# How do I get the HTML encoding to work in my ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code in an asp Gridvidiew:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlPSTNNum"  CssClass="OrdRef" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PSTNNum")%>'  runat="server" ToolTip='please click here to view the full record details'
NavigateUrl='<%#"https://THE URL IS HERE Searches/advancedsearchresults.asp?supplierid=" + Eval("Supplierid") + "&amp;display1=IS%20Number&amp;display2=Supplier&amp;display3=Product&amp;display4=Supplier%20Order%20Number&amp;order1=order%20date&amp;pstnnum=" + Eval("PSTNNum")%>' />
```

I think Visual Studio 2012 is playing up about the semicolons in the query string part (from "pstnnum=" + Eval("PSTNNum")%>' />" and i tried to escape them with \ (that keeps VS happy), but the browser leaves one of the slashes in at each escape.

Not sure the best practice here as im still cutting my coding teeth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more appropriate approach would be something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlPSTNNum"
    CssClass="OrdRef"
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PSTNNum")%>'
    runat="server"
    ToolTip='please click here to view the full record details'
    NavigateUrl='<%#Server.HtmlEncode("https://THE URL IS HERE Searches/advancedsearchresults.asp?supplierid=" + Eval("Supplierid") + "&display1=IS Number&display2=Supplier&display3=Product&display4=Supplier Order Number&order1=order date&pstnnum=" + Eval("PSTNNum"))%>' />
```

Note the use of `Server.HtmlEncode` and then the use of the actual values you want rather than the directly encoded values. This will make it easy to build in Visual Studio, but ensure it gets encoded when it's rendered.

## EDIT

After some more research into Microsoft's code I found that the base `RenderContents` method for the `HyperLink` class is going to encode this for you. That method, internally, calls another one called `ResolveClientUrl`, which looks like this:

```
public string ResolveClientUrl(string relativeUrl)
{
    if (this.DesignMode && this.Page != null && this.Page.Site != null)
    {
        IUrlResolutionService urlResolutionService = (IUrlResolutionService)this.Page.Site.GetService(typeof(IUrlResolutionService));
        if (urlResolutionService != null)
        {
            return urlResolutionService.ResolveClientUrl(relativeUrl);
        }
    }
    if (relativeUrl == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("relativeUrl");
    }
    string virtualPathString = VirtualPath.GetVirtualPathString(this.TemplateControlVirtualDirectory);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualPathString))
    {
        return relativeUrl;
    }
    string text = this.Context.Request.ClientBaseDir.VirtualPathString;
    if (!UrlPath.IsAppRelativePath(relativeUrl))
    {
        if (StringUtil.EqualsIgnoreCase(text, virtualPathString))
        {
            return relativeUrl;
        }
        if (relativeUrl.Length == 0 || !UrlPath.IsRelativeUrl(relativeUrl))
        {
            return relativeUrl;
        }
    }
    string to = UrlPath.Combine(virtualPathString, relativeUrl);
    text = UrlPath.AppendSlashToPathIfNeeded(text);
    return HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(UrlPath.MakeRelative(text, to));
}
```

Since you're URL is not relative it should fall all the way to the last line, the `return` statement, so honestly you shouldn't have to encode it at all. This changes your code to this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlPSTNNum"
    CssClass="OrdRef"
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PSTNNum")%>'
    runat="server"
    ToolTip='please click here to view the full record details'
    NavigateUrl='<%#"https://THE URL IS HERE Searches/advancedsearchresults.asp?supplierid=" + Eval("Supplierid") + "&display1=IS Number&display2=Supplier&display3=Product&display4=Supplier Order Number&order1=order date&pstnnum=" + Eval("PSTNNum")%>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this will work, but asp.net 4.5 has <%#: which encodes automatically. you can try that and see if it works, just change the <%# to <%#:

Comment: Of course, you'll probably want to get rid of the `Server.HtmlEncode` call as well.